# TFS2015: REST API for global lists

Tags: tfs-2015

I'm developing a custom dashboard widget where I have to read from a global list but I couldn't find any REST API method for this kind of operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can all [exportWorkItemTypeDefinition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236912.aspx) method using rest clients.

There are three parameters for this method:

> - project: string. Optional. Project ID or project name
> - type: string. Optional.
> - exportGlobalLists: boolean. Optional.

Specifying "project" and "type" to "null" and "exportGlobalLists" to "true", you will get the global workflow exported with global lists included in it.

---

You can still use the ***witadmin*** command-line tool to achieve

*Display the names of global lists*

```
witadmin listgloballist /collection:http://AdventureWorksServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

*Export the definition of global lists*

```
witadmin exportgloballist /collection:http://AdventureWorksServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /f:C:mygloballists
```

Source Link: [Manage global lists for work item types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236912.aspx)

Comment: It's possible to call the witadmin tool from a dashboard widget?

Comment: To access the *witadmin* command-line tool, seems you can only open a Command Prompt window where either you’ve installed a version of Visual Studio and enter:
`cd %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`  Could dashboard widget read from a .xml file which included the global list info？If can't, seems  no way.

Comment: You can also call [exportWorkItemTypeDefinition()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#exportWorkItemTypeDefinition) method using rest clients. Specifying "project" and "type" to "null" and "exportGlobalLists" to "true".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have success using [exportWorkItemTypeDefinition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236912.aspx) to achieve this. In my case, I wanted to use C# to do this purely from the back-end.

Firstly, you need to include the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client assemblies in your project. We will use that to query TFS. Secondly, I recommend installing [JB.Tfs.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JB.Tfs.Common/) which is a nice extension package that provides helper classes for managing global lists as POCO objects.

Once you have added those prerequisites, it's really a straightforward task to fetch global lists.

```
public GlobalListCollection GetGlobalLists(string url)
{
    var collectionUri = new Uri(url);
    var teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, false);
    var workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    return workItemStore.GetGlobalLists();
}
```

Url is path to the TFS collection, example:

http://example.com:8080/tfs/MyCollection