# How to get GlobalLists from Azure DevOps 2019 via RestAPI

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I try to get GlobalList from Azure DevOps via RestAPI.
So, i found method from TfsClient  - 'ExportGlobalLists' and then i should parse XML.

Have Rest Api some method to get global lists?

I found some method, but do not know is it about global lists? :

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/work/processes/lists?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Thank you!

Comment: How about use the `witadmin` command-line tool to achieve? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/manage-global-lists-for-work-item-types?view=azure-devops-2020&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vsts and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869637/tfs2015-rest-api-for-global-lists

Answer (score 1):

Your example for the picklists in the Inheritance process ([Add a picklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-picklist)). The global lists are not supported on the Rest Api.

The same question was here: [Azure DevOps API - Retrieve global lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891651/azure-devops-api-retrieve-global-lists)